# How to insert default value in odi?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I Have a map with union component that execute every night with truncate target table.
I want to insert one row with -1 value then insert my data.
how can I do it?
thanks for your help.

P.S: I have 6 tables. 3 tables join with each other(group 1) and other 3 table join with each other(group2) then group 1 union group 2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to execute an ODI procedure inserting an additional row after the mapping execution. Inserting before or after doesn't make any difference (unless you use LAG or LEAD analytical functions) as there is no default order in a table.

Alternatively, if that behavior is used for multiple tables, you can duplicate your current IKM and edit the copy to add a step inserting a row. You can also parametrize what to insert thanks to a KM option.